# I can't delete left border of Image in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to create a tableview with foods. Every cell must have:
1. Image
2. Title
3. Description

[image]

I want to move the image on the left of the cell but I can't. As you can see there is a "border on the left of the cell".

I have write this code to remove the 15px left border that apple has as default:

```
tableView.separatorInset = .zero
tableView.layoutMargins = .zero
```

The image has left constraints 0 but nothing happens.
Also if I remove the image from storyBoard, nothing happens. It's still there. (If I delete `cell.imageView?.image = item.image` from my code the image will removed)

Also As you can see I have constraints between image and labels but the text is behind the image.

[image]

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: can you show the tableview constraints?

Comment: Are you mean the content view constraints?

Comment: I mean the `UITableView` constraints

Comment: I don't have put constraints on table view. Only on the image that is inside of tableViewCell as you can see on the last image

Comment: add constraints to your tableView then, 0 leading, 0 trailing, 0 top, 0 bottom

Comment: I cant do it from StoryBoard. It's disabled. Can I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're using the UITableViewCell default ImageView, you should name your imageView with a different name from 'imageView'

Comment: How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You're replacing default UITableViewCell elements, you should subclass your cell and connect outlet to that, and so use them to setup the cell

Comment: You can follow this tutorial https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Comment: I will try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it was the correct answer, could you upvote? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

iDevid I followed the steps from link https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/ that you send me. I solved my problem with the left border but now I have problem with the constraints.

I want a screen like this:

[image]

But the result is like this:

[image]

Here is my class for the custom cell:

```
class HeadlineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var headLineImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headLineTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var headLineDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var headLineIngredientsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var headLinePriceLabel: UILabel!
}
```

I have give them text:

```
cell.headLineTitleLabel?.text = item.name
        cell.headLineDescriptionLabel?.text = item.description
        cell.headLineIngredientsLabel?.text = item.ingredients
        cell.headLinePriceLabel?.text = ("\(item.price)0€")
```

And the constraints are:

For the imageView:

[image]

For the Label 1:

[image]

For the Label 2:

[image]

For the Label 3:

[image]

For the Label 4:

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I found the answer. I had assigned the class into the Content View while it should not. Only the cell should be assigned the class!

Comment: Self solutions are always better :D